# How to find which Camunda tasks are active whether they are normal or external?

Tags: android-activity, task, camunda

In [Camunda 7.8](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.8/) I know how to get active tasks for a given process using the rest API [POST /task](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.4/reference/rest/task/post-query/).

I have a workflow that mix user tasks and external tasks. It seems that as External tasks have their own API ([POST /external-task](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.4/reference/rest/external-task/post-query/)) you can query one or the other but not both.

What I am looking for is a simple way using the Rest API to find which tasks of a Camunda process are active whether they are normal or external ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment there is no REST endpoint to query both Tasks and ExternalTasks. You could implement such an endpoint easily using [Custom Queries](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/examples/tutorials/custom-queries/) for example. Does that help you?

Cheers,
Askar

Comment: I am trying to use Camunda purely through rest call (without adding any other code), from that point the split between Task/external Task is problematic, because I have to deplicate query. I was not aware of custom query, and probably will look at it at some point.  Thanks for your answer.